# Using TinyMCE to upload images to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the WYSIWYG editor called TinyMCE. I want to make it so that users are able to upload to my server. Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
       <form method="post">
            <textarea id="editor"></textarea>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#editor',
        theme: 'modern',
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        height: 480,
        images_upload_url: 'resources/scripts/postAcceptor.php',
        images_upload_base_path: '/some/basepath',
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink link code image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
            'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
        ],

        toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | fontselect'
    });

    tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
        $.post('ajax/post.php', tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()).done(function() {
            console.log("Uploaded images and posted content as an ajax request.");
        });
    });

</script>
```

However, when I try to upload an image I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadImages' of null

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it so that users can upload images to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `tinymce.activeEditor` before TinyMCE is fully initialised.

You're going to want to put your function in an `init_instance_callback` so it's called after the editor has safely loaded. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#init_instance_callback

Comment: Inside `init_instance_callback` I put `editor.uploadImages();` the error before went away, but when I try to upload an image I get this error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.g.onload`

Comment: When I do the function that I have up there, I get a 500 server error meaning that the upload failed because there is no file to upload, but when I put in a file it gives me the unexpected token error